# UserParametersInfo doesn't blank the desktop wallpaper

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, .net-core

I'm trying to write a method that would blank my desktop. While the code is working perfectly fine on my VirtualBox machine, when I "deploy" it to some test machines it seems that the background stays as it is (with a user-defined wallpaper). I see that on the VirtualBox machine the result from UserParametersInfo is `true` whereas on Test machine it is `false`. I tried to get some error details. But `GetLastError` returns 0 so I have nothing to stick to. Here is how my code looks like:

```cs
var pathToSource = Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni("");

var result =
  User32.SystemParametersInfo(
    User32.SystemParametersInfoAction.SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER,
    0u,
    pathToSource,
    User32.SystemParametersInfoFlags.SPIF_SENDCHANGE | User32.SystemParametersInfoFlags.SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE);
```

I also tried:

1. pass as a flag only: `User32.SystemParametersInfoFlags.SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE`,
2. use User32.SystemParametersInfo build in [package](https://github.com/dotnet/pinvoke) function and my own mapping, which is visible in below code snippet,
3. create a black bitmap and pass an address to an array that contains byte representation of that bitmap.

But nothing happens.

Also, when I try to gather the path of the actual background image I got none without any error inside. The function responsible for gathering the image looks like this:

```cs
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
extern bool SystemParametersInfo(User32.SystemParametersInfoAction uiAction, uint32 uiParam, StringBuilder pvParam, User32.SystemParametersInfoFlags fWinIni)

var sb = new StringBuilder(500);

SystemParametersInfo(
  User32.SystemParametersInfoAction.SPI_GETDESKWALLPAPER,
  sb.Capacity,
  sb,
  User32.SystemParametersInfoFlags.None);
var path = sb.ToString();
```

I'm testing it on newest Windows 10, .net core 3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your presented code seems not ready to run. (You define `pathToSource` but pass in `path`. )

The following code works for me (.Net Core 2.2 and Windows 10 1909) and you can have a try to see if it works for you.

```
class Program
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    extern static bool SystemParametersInfo(UInt32 uiAction, UInt32 uiParam, IntPtr pvParam, UInt32 fWinIni);
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var pathToSource = Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni("");

        var result = SystemParametersInfo(
          0x0014, // #define SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER        0x0014
          0,
          pathToSource,
          0x0002 | 0x0001); // SPIF_SENDCHANGE | SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE

        if (result)
        {
            // Example #2: Write one string to a text file.
            string text = "SystemParametersInfo success!\n ";
            // WriteAllText creates a file, writes the specified string to the file,
            // and then closes the file.    You do NOT need to call Flush() or Close().
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"[path to]\test.txt", text);
        }
        else {
            Int32 errCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            // Example #2: Write one string to a text file.
            string text = "SystemParametersInfo fails! Error code is " + errCode.ToString();
            // WriteAllText creates a file, writes the specified string to the file,
            // and then closes the file.    You do NOT need to call Flush() or Close().
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"[path to]\test.txt", text);
        }
    }
}
```

As we already found that above code does work in an application. However, in a Windows Service, there are limitations to access graphical user interface (GUI). You will receive error code `1459` which indicate "This operation requires an interactive window station." when using an noninteractive service. **Services cannot directly interact with a user as of Windows Vista.** Refer to "[Interacting with a User from a Service Indirectly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/interactive-services#interacting-with-a-user-from-a-service-indirectly)" for how to interact with users in new code.

**So to achieve this purpose you may want to add a separate hidden GUI application and use the `CreateProcessAsUser` function to run the application within the context of the interactive user. Send message from your service to the hidden GUI application to tell when and how to execute the task of changing wallpaper.**

Comment: @rita-han-msft unfortunately the result with the code that you posted is exactly the same. The actual wallpaper path wasn't resolved nor background was set to a solid color. Everything works fine on Windows that is located in a Virtual Box, but not on a standalone machine. No errors either in `LastError` :(

Comment: @MNie Could change the wallpaper to an image at location C:\Windows\Web\Wallpaper (For example: C:\Windows\Web\Wallpaper\Windows\img0.jpg) via settings -> Personalization -> Background and then run the code again?

Comment: @rita-han-msft still the same. I used built-in windows wallpapers and my own. The result is the same, the path for an image is empty and change to blank desktop doesn't happen.

Comment: @MNie There seems an issue. When I specify a invalid file path the function still return true and the last error is `0`.  However at this time the wallpaper change to solid color black. The *solid color black* is what you are looking for as *blank*?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I mean as `blank`. But the clue is that after some time I want to fallback to user-defined wallpaper, so even if I could blank the wallpaper I have to somehow fetch the current one. But fetching the path of the current wallpaper also doesn't work :(

Comment: @MNie What's your Windows 10 build version? And does your code run in a service or an app?

Comment: @rita-han-msft it works as a service. Os build version on the physical machine: 18362.900, on the virtual box: 18362.418.

Comment: @MNie Could you test the same code in an app to see if it works? And how do you configure the service, for example, is it an interactive service?

Comment: @rita-han-msft I could create some console application and see if that works. Service receives any user interaction with the screen and pass it through to another service/microservice. It is also responsible for getting data from another microservice and "put it in" actual machine (for example keystrokes, moving mouse, etc.).

Comment: @MNie Please check my update answer to check how to log error code in service and how to change wallpaper in new code.

Comment: @rita-han-msft I already "create" a process in the context of an interactive user. But I thought that "if it is working on Virtualbox but not on a physical machine, it shouldn't be a problem here". But it seems that it is :(. Moving the code to the interactive user process fixed the issue. The sad thing is that I didn't receive the error code at all :(. Could you please enlarge/bold the final paragraph since this is the essence of the answer (for me), thanks!